# Configure arrows in pgf-umlsd

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

A standard diagram produced by `pgf-umlsd` uses only basic arrows, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit, calc, shapes, arrows}
\usepackage[underline=false]{pgf-umlsd}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{sequencediagram}
        \newinst{c}{Client}
        \newinst[6]{s}{Server}

        \mess[1]{c}{Longer label}{s}
        \mess[1]{s}{label}{c}
        \mess[1]{c}{label}{s}
        \mess[1]{s}{Longer label}{c}
    \end{sequencediagram}
    \caption{Client-Server messaging}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to adjust the length and the tip of any given arrow. For example, being able to draw something like:

[image]

Can this be done by applying local changes to a figure?

Comment: Is the application of e.g. `tikzpicture` a valuable alternative to `sequencediagram` because then you can/have to draw everything by hand. You are including the package `tikz` anyway. Are you interested in such a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it can be done by a redefinition of `\mess`; in the following example I used [`xparse`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse) to easily add a fifth optional argument allowing you some control over the `\draw` command used for the arrow; this, in particular, allows you to specify different arrow tips and to use the `shorten` key:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit, calc, shapes, arrows}
\usepackage[underline=false]{pgf-umlsd}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\mess}{O{0}mmmO{>=angle 60}}{%
  \stepcounter{seqlevel}
  \path
  (#2)+(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-0.7*\unitfactor) node (mess from) {};
  \addtocounter{seqlevel}{#1}
  \path
  (#4)+(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-0.7*\unitfactor) node (mess to) {};
  \draw[->,#5] (mess from) -- (mess to) node[midway, above]
  {#3};

  \node (#3 from) at (mess from) {};
  \node (#3 to) at (mess to) {};
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{sequencediagram}
        \newinst{c}{Client}
        \newinst[6]{s}{Server}

        \mess[1]{c}{Longer label}{s}[{-]},shorten >=20pt]
        \mess[1]{s}{label}{c}[>=hooks,shorten >=10pt]
        \mess[1]{c}{label}{s}
        \mess[1]{s}{Longer label}{c}
    \end{sequencediagram}
    \caption{Client-Server messaging}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To produce the exact tip arrow you showed in your question, you need, for example, to have the CVS version of `pgf`, then you already have this kind of arrow in `arrows.meta` library.