# Align label parallel to arrow in pgf-umlsd

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, pgf-umlsd

This is a MWE for a sequence diagram using `pgf-umlsd`: (taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155279))

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit, calc, shapes, arrows}
\usepackage[underline=false]{pgf-umlsd}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{sequencediagram}
        \newinst{c}{Client}
        \newinst[6]{s}{Server}

        \mess[1]{c}{Longer label}{s}
        \mess[1]{s}{label}{c}
        \mess[1]{c}{label}{s}
        \mess[1]{s}{Longer label}{c}
    \end{sequencediagram}
    \caption{Client-Server messaging}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can each label be aligned in parallel to its corresponding arrow?

Comment: From looking at the code, I don't think it is possible out of the box. You'll need extra options given to the nodes on the paths, and `\mess` does not provide this. Have a look in `pgf-umlsd.sty`, you can easily make your own version of `\mess` it is a fairly simple macro.

Comment: And please don't use `[H]`, learn to use floats properly, then there is no need for `[H]`.

Comment: Basically you'll need to add the `sloped` option to the `midway` node  in the last  `\path` in the `\mess` definition.

Comment: Thank's a lot, it works. Can you post your comments as an answer such that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code for `pgf-umlsd.sty` we get that `\mess` is defined as

```
% message between threads
% Example:
% \mess[delay]{sender}{message content}{receiver}
\newcommand{\mess}[4][0]{
  \stepcounter{seqlevel}
  \path
  (#2)+(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-0.7*\unitfactor) node (mess from) {};
  \addtocounter{seqlevel}{#1}
  \path
  (#4)+(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-0.7*\unitfactor) node (mess to) {};
  \draw[->,>=angle 60] (mess from) -- (mess to) node[midway, above]
  {#3};

  \node (#3 from) at (mess from) {};
  \node (#3 to) at (mess to) {};
}
```

The node with the `midway` option is the node we are looking for. As we can see `\mess` does not give any way of adding configurations to that node.

I'd just copy the code for `\mess`, call it `\messS` and in that code, just add `sloped` to the options for the `midway` node.

BTW: please don't use the `[H]` float placement. This is often a sign that you are not using floats in the proper manner.